# How to push a new object to an array if not already in localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I am trying to implement a simple 'add to favorites' feature but can't quite get things working in local storage.

I am able to push an object/array to local storage and retrieve it back but when I click on the next item to 'add to favorites' I end up overwriting the previous one rather than adding a new object to the array.

code below:

```
 const push1 = async (movieId, movieName, image) => {
    const stringId = JSON.stringify(movieId);
    const stringName = JSON.stringify(movieName);
    const stringImage = JSON.stringify(image);

    // our array
    let moviesList = [];

    // our object
    let movies = {
      movieId: stringId,
      movieName: stringName,
      image: stringImage
    };

    moviesList.push(movies);

    // storing our array as a string
    localStorage.setItem("movieList", JSON.stringify(moviesList));

    let updatedMoviesList = [];

    const retrievedMovies = localStorage.getItem("movieList");
    const parseRetrievedMovies = JSON.parse(retrievedMovies);
    console.log("retrievedMovies: ", retrievedMovies);
    console.log("parseRetrievedMovies: ", parseRetrievedMovies);
    parseRetrievedMovies.push(movies);
};
```

How can I update the array if the same object is not already there?

Comment: localhost.getItem returns null is nothing is there. Just check it before push. Also no need for first 3 lines ->    const stringId = JSON.stringify(movieId); . Create full normal object then before adding to the localhost make stringify.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead which helps you store unique movies in `localStorage`.

Try as the following:

```js
const stringId = '12';
const stringName = 'Name';
const stringImage = '<img-url>';

const moviesList = new Set();

const movie = {
  movieId: stringId,
  movieName: stringName,
  image: stringImage
};

moviesList.add(JSON.stringify(movie));
console.log('first attempt', JSON.parse(Array.from(moviesList)));

moviesList.add(JSON.stringify(movie));
console.log('second attempt', JSON.parse(Array.from(moviesList)));
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check if object is alreadyin retreived movies using `array.some` and only if not present push it.

```
const retrievedMovies = localStorage.getItem("movieList");
if(retrievedMovies) {
   const parseRetrievedMovies = JSON.parse(retrievedMovies);
   console.log("retrievedMovies: ", retrievedMovies);
   console.log("parseRetrievedMovies: ", parseRetrievedMovies);
   const movieExists = parseRetrievedMovies.some((m) => movies.movieId === m.movieId ))
   if(!movieExists) {
      parseRetrievedMovies.push(movies);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't reading the old setting. Instead you're starting with a new, empty array:

```
let moviesList = [];
```

Here you could instead load the data saved last time, like this:

```
let moviesList = localStorage.getItem("movieList");
```

Then modify it by adding the new movie, then save, as you are already doing.

Hope this helps.